# Xposed : How to hook a method of a nested class(inner class) in xposed framework.

Tags: android, nested, systems-programming

I am trying to hook a method using:

```
 findAndHookMethod("com.android.keyguard.KeyguardPatternView.UnlockPatternListener", lpparam.classLoader, "onPatternDetected", new XC_MethodHook()
```

Where UnlockPatternListener is a nested class(inner class) and it has a method called onPatternDetected. 
The inner class is private.

I am unable to hook this method. Can you tell me the way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should work this way

```
 findAndHookMethod("com.android.keyguard.KeyguardPatternView$UnlockPatternListener", lpparam.classLoader, "onPatternDetected", new XC_MethodHook()
                                                            ^
```